# MediaPlayer in separate Thread vs running in Service via startForeground()

Tags: android

So, I'm streaming music in a separate thread. If I leave the app (`onPause()`, `onStop()` getting called, etc), the music continues to play, but eventually -- after opening other apps and switching between them and going back to the home screen -- my app is killed. No crash, just a `WIN DEATH` and `process com.myapp.android has died` in logcat. Obviously, it's legit for apps to be destroyed by the system in order to reclaim resources.

My question is: does running stuff in a thread off of the main (UI) thread mean that it now has less priority as far as the system is concerned? Meaning, is it more likely to be killed than if I run the media player in a `Service` and even use `startForeground()` to make the service run in the foreground?

Any thoughts or clarification would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**

Also, part of the documentation on Services confuses me. In pertinent part, it states:

> Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the
>   service does not   create its own thread and does not run in a
>   separate process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if
>   your service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking
>   operations (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a
>   new thread within the service to do that work.

I've always ran MP3 playback in a service on the main thread and the UI remained responsive. If I'm supposed to put it in a separate thread as recommended in the above quotation, then won't I end up back where I started, namely with the media playback occuring off of the main thread, thereby increasing the likelihood that the playback is killed when other apps are opened, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think most of your question is answered in the [Android documentation on Services](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html).

From the link:

> A foreground service is a service that's considered to be something
>   the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for the system
>   to kill when low on memory. A foreground service must provide a
>   notification for the status bar, which is placed under the "Ongoing"
>   heading, which means that the notification cannot be dismissed unless
>   the service is either stopped or removed from the foreground.

To answer your question, yes, running a separate `Thread` off of an `Activity` is going to have lower priority than a `Service` running in the foreground, *if the `Activity` that started the `Thread` has been stopped/paused.*

Personally, I would recommend doing this in a `Service`, as this is exactly the sort of thing the `Service` class has been created for.

***Edit:***

Interesting, what you suggest seems contrary to what I have read (everything is responsive when not using thread in `Service`).  Regardless, it probably should be started in a background thread.

The thread (a thread that YOU create) won't die unless the process dies, and that will happen when the runtime decides that resources are needed.  `Activity`'s can be killed when they are not in the foreground, so their `Thread`'s can be destroyed too.  If you have a `Service` marked as foreground, it is less likely to be destroyed, and therefore, you should not have the same problem.

Comment: I have placed my mediaplayer both within a service and outside of one running on in its own thread. Android will kill mediaplayer regardless where it is located if it needs more resources. And it isn't even less likely to be killed within a service that has foreground priority than in a separate thread. The only place where it seems to never get killed is in an activity that is currently in the foreground.

Answer (score 8):

I just posted part of this answer elsewhere, but it's still relevant.

Unfortunately, calling prepareAsync() is simply not good enough to avoid ANR prompts and your application hanging for a few seconds, especially if you're playing a file from the network. Your best bet is to put your MediaPlayer instance in its own thread, or at the very least execute intensive calls in a Handler (like mediaplayer.start()). I've been using MediaPlayer for over a year and I can tell you it definitely hangs after various calls, depending on the circumstances.

Ideally, you should be spawning a thread that controls your MediaPlayer from a Service. That way you ensure your media continues to play while your app is in the background and any blocking calls (aside from prepare()/prepareAsync()) do not hang your app.

Comment: I concur. However I must add that I have seen mediaplayer get terminated even in a thread spawned from a service. It appears that mediaplayer has its own internal threading which has an even lower priority than a foreground service and that Android is more willing to kill off a spawned thread before it terminates the service.

Comment: So, I think this addresses the issue better than the accepted. Anyway, what I want to know is, do I need to run a separate thread even in a service? Currently, I am using an entirely different process but want to move it to the main process.

Comment: Service by default runs on the main UI thread. We can create a Thread/AsyncTask in the Service. That's pretty much how I would do it.

Answer (score -1):

There's no need to run a MediaPlayer from a thread. As long as you use MediaPlayer.prepareAsync, rather than MediaPlayer.prepare, there are no methods on MediaPlayer that will block long enough to cause problems. Run it on the foreground thread of your Service.

If your process gets killed, the threads are going with it. Processes that host Services have a longer lifetime than Activities, provided you call the Service.startForeground method (and display the mandatory notification requried by startForeground on the status bar). As soon as an Activity pauses, the entire process becomes a prime candidate for recycling (asuming there isn't a foreground service in the process as well).

Comment: Unfortunately while the documentation seems to indicate prepareAsync() is good enough, it's not enough. Other calls other than prepare() can hang the app, so it is better for a MediaPlayer instance to be in its own thread.