# Should a MediaPlayer run in separate thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, streaming, media-player

I'm building an app that streams music from a web server. The app has foreground service that uses a MediaPlayer for playback.

My code is based on this example: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html

In the example, nothing is threaded except the prepareAsync() call. What confuses me is that when I read about the Service class I find this information:

*"Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process—the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process (unless you specify otherwise). This means that, if your service is going to do any CPU intensive work or blocking operations (such as MP3 playback or networking), you should create a new thread within the service to do that work. By using a separate thread, you will reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors and the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction with your activities."*

The reason I'm asking is that the app some times (usually when loosing connection) freezes the UI when streaming audio. I totally understand that the UI freezes if the service is making CPU intense work, since the activity and the service runs on the same thread. But, should I expect the MediaPlayer to be this intense? That is, should it run on a separate thread?

Comment: readh ere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8915618/mediaplayer-in-separate-thread-vs-running-in-service-via-startforeground

Comment: I'd definitely advice not to make any blocking calls to Audiomanager, MediaPlayer, AudioRecord, et al from your application's main thread. If the audio system becomes temporarily bogged down - or completely stops responding - for some reason you'll just end up with an ANR in your app, and a bug report that isn't likely to be useful to anyone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Michael! I totally agree with you on that blocking calls should run in a separate thread. But, should I expect the media playback to become blocking? I just can't find a way to tell if the media player is becoming "blocking" or what is causing this. This only happens when I'm streaming over rtsp while traveling by car or train. Perhaps changing cell tower could be a problem? Currently, I'm relying on the MediaPlayer to solve that, which does most of the times.

Comment: I don't remember off the top of my head which methods are synchronous and which are not. But if the documentation doesn't state that a given method is asynchronous you should assume that it can take an indefinite amount of time to return. Under most conditions that time will not be long enough to cause apps to ANR. However, in order to avoid ANRs even in situations where these methods do _not_ return promptly (for whatever reason) you should not be calling them from your main thread.

Answer (score 14):

Unfortunately, calling prepareAsync() is simply not good enough to avoid ANR prompts and your application hanging for a few seconds, especially if you're playing a file from the network. Your best bet is to put your MediaPlayer instance in its own thread, or at the very least execute intensive calls in a Handler (like `mediaplayer.start()`).  I've been using MediaPlayer for over a year and I can tell you it definitely hangs after various calls, depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Could the streaming music be causing the main thread to stop until the music has finished streaming? This could be why it is slowing it right down.

I'm no expert and am currently learning myself, but it's worth thinking about.

Answer (score -2):

No if you are doing any network transfer you should keep that in a thread, mediaplayer is not that resource intensive. Keep it on your activity.

Comment: You don't want to keep your mediaplayer in an activity since it should run even if activity is destroyed. You should run it in a foreground service.