# Should MediaPlayer.start() also be a new thread?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-mediaplayer

The tutorial here explains that a service actually uses the main thread. So it uses `prepareAsync` to avoid blocking UIS:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#asyncprepare

I was wondering where the async callback `onPrepared` runs. In the example `onPrepared` calls start of `MediaPlayer`. Is start also a CPU-intensive method? If it runs in the same thread, it also blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MediaPlayer.start()` is not an intensive operation in the least. The `MediaPlayer` uses its own native thread to perform tasks, but a call to the synchronous `prepare` method can take too long for the UI thread, particularly if it is remote media you are trying to play. In that case it has to wait for one or more network requests, data to buffer, etc. The `onPrepared` callback will happen on the main thread if that is where you called `prepareAsync` (or whatever thread you called it from, to be more precise).

Comment: Doesn't this answer oppose http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658583/should-a-mediaplayer-run-in-separate-thread ?

Comment: Depends. `start()` is definitely not an "intensive call", and running it in a `Handler` doesn't automatically imply it would be run in a different thread. That said, the best setup IMO is to put the `MediaPlayer` in a `Service` that runs on its own process. This answer merely addresses what the OP asked as it relates to the example in the link.

Comment: In my experience, doing multitrack audio (eight simultaneous MP3s) actually does cause some performance problems if the MediaPlayers are not moved to their own thread.