# How to play music in a separate Thread?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I wanted to play music in a separate thread, however I confused whether to create Media Player in a thread, or start the music in a thread?
The following method starts the music in a thread:

```
public void startMusic(final MediaPlayer music){
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            music.start();
        }
    };

    thread.start();
}
```

Is this correct one?

Comment: whats wrong in starting `MediaPlayer` in the main UI thread? why to make own life harder?

Comment: @Enzokie Do I have to create new music like "music = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mus_1);" in this thread? Then start the music.

Comment: @pskink I just wanted to be sure that Music would not force the UI thread.

Comment: then dont use `prepare()` method - the docs say: *"Prepares the player for playback, synchronously. After setting the datasource and the display surface, you need to either call prepare() or prepareAsync(). For files, it is OK to call prepare(), which blocks until MediaPlayer is ready for playback."*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should MediaPlayer.start() also be a new thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21438583/should-mediaplayer-start-also-be-a-new-thread)

Comment: additionally you should read this: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: @williMentzel  Thanks everyone, I am gonna use the main thread. My last question, I did not call the prepare() method, was it called in the onCreate() method?

Comment: see where `prepare()` is called under the [hood](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/media/java/android/media/MediaPlayer.java) - lines #912 and #977

Comment: @pskink Thanks man!