# Example of a service that does not perform "intensive or blocking operations"

Tags: android

Just reading the [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Basics) for Services in Android and I had a question about this part:

> Caution: A services runs in the same process as the application in which it is declared and in the main thread of that application, by default. So, if your service performs intensive or blocking operations while the user interacts with an activity from the same application, the service will slow down activity performance. To avoid impacting application performance, you should start a new thread inside the service

My question is, what is an example of a service that is run in the same application that does NOT perform "intensive or blocking operations?"

Would playing music be an example?

I'm just wondering why I would ever use a service WITHOUT an AsyncTask or a new thread inside of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example service receiving push notifications or sensor updates usually does not perform any blocking or intensive operations. Playing music using `MediaPlayer` [may block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17066063/4538344).

Answer (score 0):

Your Service can for example perform calls to an asynchronous API: An API which only works with callbacks and is designed to manage its own threads internally, like: Google Play Services or Volley or RxJava.

In that case there is no need to use the background thread you get when you use IntentService.