# Is Android MediaPlayer multithreaded?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Can we create and use Android MediaPlayer from a background thread?

I ask because it's strange that all callback events (like `OnError`, `OnPrepared`, `OnVideoSizeChanged`, etc..) are fired in the main UI thread and this happens even if the MediaPlayer was created (and used) inside a background thread.

Comment: Have a look at [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658583/should-a-mediaplayer-run-in-separate-thread) if you already not.

Comment: @ADM thanks but nothing really interesting in the discussion you point me :( they just say to use MediaPlayer in background thread (without any clear doc that say we can do) and noone explain if it's can work and why all event are fired in the main ui thread

Comment: Ok . I think you should read [Media Player](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html) . And also Test it on a Sample with background creation. Post the answer after your effort whatever output you get . It will help others . Thx

Comment: i read media player, and nothing point that it's should be used in background thread !

Comment: Well as i said create a sample if it worth for you . Then only you can reach a conclusion .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and use `MediaPlayer` from background thread. But to receive callbacks on the background thread that thread must have `Looper` implemented. If thread does not have `Looper` callbacks will be called on the main (UI) thread.

From Android documentation [MediaPlayer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html):

> **Callbacks**
>
> Applications may want to register for informational and
>   error events in order to be informed of some internal state update and
>   possible runtime errors during playback or streaming. Registration for
>   these events is done by properly setting the appropriate listeners
>   (via calls to
>   setOnPreparedListener(OnPreparedListener)setOnPreparedListener,
>   setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(OnVideoSizeChangedListener)setOnVideoSizeChangedListener,
>   setOnSeekCompleteListener(OnSeekCompleteListener)setOnSeekCompleteListener,
>   setOnCompletionListener(OnCompletionListener)setOnCompletionListener,
>   setOnBufferingUpdateListener(OnBufferingUpdateListener)setOnBufferingUpdateListener,
>   setOnInfoListener(OnInfoListener)setOnInfoListener,
>   setOnErrorListener(OnErrorListener)setOnErrorListener, etc).
>
> In order
>   to receive the respective callback associated with these listeners,
>   applications are required to create MediaPlayer objects on a thread
>   with its own **Looper** running (main UI thread by default has a Looper
>   running).

---

Most basic example to observe difference between creating `MediaPlayer` on threads with or without `Lopper`:

```
        HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("mp") {
//        Thread thread = new Thread() {

        @Override
        public void onLooperPrepared() {
//        public void run() {
            Log.d("XAPP", "BG Thread " + Long.toString(Thread.currentThread().getId()));
            MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.sound);
            player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
                {
                    Log.d("XAPP", "onPrepared " + Long.toString(Thread.currentThread().getId()));
                    mp.start();
                }
            });

            player.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
                {
                    Log.d("XAPP", "onCompletion " + Long.toString(Thread.currentThread().getId()));
                }
            });

        }};

        thread.start();
```

`HandlerThread` has a `Looper` and running the above code will result in following logcat output . all callbacks are executed on background thread

```
01-11 14:33:04.122 5099-5099/xxx D/XAPP: UI Thread 1
01-11 14:33:04.122 5099-5173/xxx D/XAPP: BG Thread 416
01-11 14:33:04.152 5099-5173/xxx D/XAPP: onPrepared 416
01-11 14:33:05.133 5099-5173/xxx D/XAPP: onCompletion 416
```

Switching to `Thread` implementation (uncomment `Thread()` line and `run()` line, and comment `HandlerThread()` and `onLooperPrepared(`) lines) that does not have `Looper` will yield following logcat where callbacks are executed in the context of main thread

```
01-11 14:31:45.706 4916-4916/xxx D/XAPP: UI Thread 1
01-11 14:31:45.706 4916-4994/xxx D/XAPP: BG Thread 413
01-11 14:31:45.736 4916-4916/xxx D/XAPP: onPrepared 1
01-11 14:31:46.717 4916-4916/xxx D/XAPP: onCompletion 1
```