# Playing 6 videos in 6 Textureview

Tags: android

I would really appreciate if you can help me with this problem:

How can i play 6 videos in 6 different Textureviews using 6 different MediaPlayers.

I'm using the next code(which comes from [Playing video on TextureView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736517/playing-video-on-textureview))

```
public class MediaPlayerDemo_Video extends Activity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

private TextureView mPreview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

  super.onCreate(icicle);

  mPreview = new TextureView(this);
  mPreview.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
  ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
  mPreview.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

  extras = getIntent().getExtras();

  setContentView(mPreview);
}

 @Override
 public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surface, int width, int height) {
 Surface s = new Surface(surface);

 try {
   mMediaPlayer= new MediaPlayer();
   mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp");
   mMediaPlayer.setSurface(s);
   mMediaPlayer.prepare();
   mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
   mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
   mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
   mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);
   mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
   mMediaPlayer.start();
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (SecurityException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }   
}
```

Comment: I think this post can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48207214/is-android-mediaplayer-multithreaded